# css transform:rotate property, unwanted border

Tags: html, css

I am using the css transform property to rotate the logo of a webpage. The logo itself is made up of several inner divs with relative and absolute position. I have an outer div holding the whole thing with the id of wholeLogo, and I put this in the style sheet to rotate it:

```
#wholeLogo {
    border: none;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transform: rotate(-7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-7deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-7deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-7deg); 
}
```

The logo is rotated correctly, but I am getting a strange dashed border around each of the divs inside the wholeLogo div. Does anyone know why this would happen and how to make it stop?

Here is Fiddle requested:

http://jsfiddle.net/CbsUT/1/

If you are wondering why there are two copies of each piece of the logo, it is because I want color gradient and text shadow. But these two things don't seem to play nice with each other so I made one copy with one and another with the other and overlapped them.

Worst case scenario is I unrotate it, do a screen capture, rotate it in paint or something, and bring it back as a picture, but I would like to avoid this if possible.

Comment: May we see a fiddle? And what happen if you don't rotate it?

Comment: Maybe it's the pixels of the inner divs not quite lining up when rotated - is the 'border' the colour of the div behind?

Comment: @Passerby. Fiddle is added. There is no border when not rotated.

Comment: @zenkaty: I think you are on to something. I am using some color gradient on the picture and I think it's seeping through. What's weird is how its a dashed border though.

Comment: Had a look at the fiddle, yep it's definitely the edges of the gradient shape 'bleeding' through. Because of your z-index settings, the colour is on top of the containing shape, so I can't think of any way to "cover" it... Sorry!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CbsUT/2/ This is what I've tried by far. It's far from perfect (or maybe depends on client machine; I'm using an old XP here), but I'm out of idea, so I post here and hopefully it will inspire you...Essentially this relates to how Webkit handle object edges when rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

HTML : -

```
<div id="wholeLogo">
  <h1 data-title="Logo"> <a href="#">Logo</a> </h1>
</div>
```

CSS : -

```
#wholeLogo {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 35px;
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(7deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(7deg);
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:100px;
    text-shadow: 2px 3px 1px #292929;
}

h1 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #0032ff;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(20%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

h1 a:hover {
    color: #0032ff;
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(0,0,0,.3)), to(rgba(0,0,0,1)));
}

h1:after {
    color: #dc0000;
    content : attr(data-title);
}
```